# How do I resolve a resource conflict issue on Tableau Server 2019.1.1?

Tags: tableau-api

I'm running into an issue with Tableau Server 2019.1.1 where I'm unable to generate Ziplogs due to a "Resource Conflict" error message. I suspect this is the same reason why I'm not able to generate log files in the TSM interface as well. Has anyone encountered a similar issue and found a workaround? I'm not able to find much through a Google search.

```
2019-04-23 10:00:39.102 -0400  qtp1039551172-12074 : INFO  com.tableausoftware.config.ServiceRegistrationInfoFile - no registration file found at 
2019-04-23 10:00:39.102 -0400  qtp1039551172-12074 : WARN  com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.configuration.builder.AppConfigurationBuilder - Unable to flatten service registration info, because there is no registration file.
2019-04-23 10:12:53.503 -0400  qtp1039551172-12052 : INFO  com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.GlobalExceptionHandler - Handling client exception com.tableausoftware.tabadmin.webapp.exceptions.ResourceConflictRestException: errors.resource_conflict.summary: C:\Users\Admin_User\Desktop
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try running `tsm maintenance cleanup` before running your backup?

Also, do you have IPv6 enabled on your server?  If so, it should be disabled.

Comment: No and I'm not able to since I need to gather metrics for several months to a year for analysis. IPv6 is disabled.

Comment: I would suggest opening up a case with Tableau Support so they can dig into the log files to see exactly what is going on.  https://www.tableau.com/support/case

Comment: Thanks tagyoureit